# How to work around a nonconvex constraint?

Tags: optimization, numerical-optimization

My objective function is

\begin{align}
\text{minimize}_{\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^3} \quad & \mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{M}\mathbf{x} \\
\text{subject to }\quad &  x_1 = 1\\ & x_3=x_1x_2=x_2
\end{align}

where 
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{M} = \begin{bmatrix}
M_{11} & M_{12} &   M_{13}       \\
M_{21} & M_{22} &   M_{23}      \\
M_{31} & M_{32} &   M_{33}      \\
            \end{bmatrix},
\end{equation}

and

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{x} = \begin{bmatrix}
x_{1} \\
x_{2} \\
x_{3} \\
            \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

is a randomly generated symmetric positive definite matrix.

Objective function is convex but what about $x_3=x_2$ constraint?
Any ideas about how to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

The constraint $x_2=x_3$ is convex, and indeed if we eliminate $x_1$ and let $x_2=x_3=x$ then the optimization problem is equivalent to $\min M_{11}+(M_{12}+M_{13}+M_{21}+M_{31})x+(M_{22}+M_{23}+M_{32}+M_{33})x^2$, meaning that if the quadratic term is negative then the problem is unbounded, and otherwise it can be solved analytically by completing the square.